# Powershell where-object syntax - Hyphen in attribute

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below to target only relevant users.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $TargetOU -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.adminDescription -eq "Azure_Sync" -and $_.proxyAddresses -notlike "sip*" -and $_.sn -ne $null -and $_.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress -ne $null
```

However, it's not liking the last one $_.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress. The "-" is breaking things here so how do I go about using this attribute in the same way as the others?

Comment: add qoutes around it : $_."msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"

Comment: Use `$_."msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"`

Comment: Alternatively `$PSItem["msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add quotes around the property like

```
$_."msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"
```

Comment: Thanks. I honestly didn't realise quotes could be used for the attribute in this syntax. The colour of attribute changed in the ISE console as soon as "-" was used and using quotes makes it look like a simple string but obviously not the case. Thanks again, works a treat.